# How to create a string from variadic

Tags: go

I have a function that accepts a variadic string argument like this:

```
func RunCommand(command string, args ...string) {
}
```

Now for logging purposes, I need to construct a string which consists of the command + arguments.

So I need to have a single string variable that includes both arguments.

How to do that in Go?

Comment: `log.Println(command, args)`?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks but how can I create a variable string from command and args before printing?

Comment: You can use [`strings.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join). For example `strings.Join(append([]string{command}, args...), ",")` (change `","` to whatever you desire the separator to be).

Comment: @mkopriva great, thanks a lot, would you please post it as answer?

Comment: If it's all the same to you you can accept Shrikant's answer.

Comment: Shrikant's answer is fine as well, but I was looking for something provided by the language itself, that's why I wanted to accept your answer

Comment: `strings.Join`, loop over them with `for`, it really depends on what you want the output to actually end up like, which isn't specified in the question.

Comment: @Adrian I believe I mentioned that I need to concatenate the two arguments into one string. And I had the for loop idea in mind, just because I'm new to Go I expected another way provided by the language itself which is strings.Join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the straight forward way of doing this can be like below -

```
func sum(command string, args ...string) {
    for _, arg := range args {
        command += " " + arg
    }
    fmt.Println(command)
}
```

Also thanks to [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) it can be achieved this way as well:

```
strings.Join(append([]string{command}, args...), ",")
```